# MSDeploy API - Deleting a remote file through code

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

I am looking to remotely fire a delete command using the MSDeploy API through c# code.

I want to achieve the following command:

`msdeploy.exe -verb:delete -dest:contentPath="/folderName/filename.txt"`

instead of through running an unmanaged external executable, I want to execute this using the MSDeploy .Net API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer thanks to Richard Szalay's leading and i've used the `ContentPath` provider as this is a common provider used by VS Publishing so the chances of having permissions is high:

```
var deployBaseOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions
{
    ComputerName = "https://mywebserver.com:8172/msdeploy.axd?sitename=yourIISWebsiteName",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    UseDelegation = true,
    AuthenticationType = "Basic"
};
var syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions
{
    DeleteDestination = true
};
var deploymentObject = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.ContentPath,
                                                        "yourIISWebsiteName" + "/fileToDelete.txt",
                                                        destBaseOptions);

var results = deploymentObject.SyncTo(deployBaseOptions, syncOptions);
```

The weird thing is that `results` always shows 3 files deleted even when there is only one...?!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to delete an absolute filepath (rather than a file in a website), you're looking for something like this:

```
DeploymentObject destObject = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(
    DeploymentWellKnownProvider.FilePath, "/foldername/filename.txt");

DeploymentObject sourceObject = DeploymentManager.CreateObject("auto", "");

DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions();
DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions
{
    DeleteDestination = true;
};

DeploymentChangeSummary results = sourceObject.SyncTo(
   destObject, baseOptions, syncOptions);

// results.ObjectsDeleted == 1
```

Comment: These overloads don't appear to exist. SyncTo doesn't take in a DeploymentObject.